# Show/Hide models in JSC3D

Tags: javascript, 3d, show-hide

I have a JSC3D scene that contains multiple files.  My goal would be to show/hide one of the models with an onClick call.
The two options I can come up with are to recreate the scene with the one model missing, or to somehow access a visible property of one of the models.
I've tried various permutations of the alert code to access the visible property, but no luck there.  The updateview function was my attempt to recreate the scene with the missing model.  BTW, if you change colors[newLoaded] to colors[newLoaded+1] the colors will update, but the displayed models remain the same.
It has been many years since I looked into this stuff so I am sure it is something easy that I am missing
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Crown Study Ranking</TITLE>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsc3d/jsc3d.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsc3d/jsc3d.webgl.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsc3d/jsc3d.touch.js"></script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <div style="width:800px; margin:auto; position:relative;">
        <canvas id="cv" style="border: 1px solid;" width="750" height="400">
            It seems you are using an outdated browser that does not support canvas :-(
        </canvas>

    <form action="">
          <input type="checkbox" name="antagonist" value="1" onClick="this.value = -1*this.value; updateview(this.name,this.value);" checked> Antagonist</input>
          <input type="checkbox" name="arch" value="1" onClick="this.value = -1*this.value; updateview(this.name,this.value);" checked> Main Arch</input>
          <input type="checkbox" name="crown" value="1" onClick="this.value = -1*this.value; updateview(this.name,this.value);" checked> Crown</input>
    </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById('cv');
    var viewer = new JSC3D.Viewer(canvas);
    var components = ['models/dummy.stl', 'models/dummya.stl', 'models/dummyc.stl'];
    var colors = [0xff0000, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0xffff00, 0x00ffff];
    var theScene = new JSC3D.Scene;
    var numOfLoaded = 0;

    var onModelLoaded = function(scene) {
        var meshes = scene.getChildren();
        for (var i=0; i<meshes.length; i++) {
            theScene.addChild(meshes[i]);
            if (meshes.length > 0) 
               meshes[0].setMaterial(new JSC3D.Material('red-material', 0, colors[numOfLoaded])); 
        }
            if (++numOfLoaded == components.length)
            viewer.replaceScene(theScene);
    };

    for (var i=0; i<components.length; i++) {
        var loader = new JSC3D.StlLoader;
        loader.onload = onModelLoaded;
        loader.loadFromUrl(components[i]);
    }

    viewer.setParameter('ModelColor', '#FF0000');
    viewer.setParameter('BackgroundColor1', '#E5D7BA');
    viewer.setParameter('BackgroundColor2', '#383840');
    viewer.setParameter('RenderMode', 'flat');
    viewer.setParameter('Renderer', 'webgl');
    viewer.init();
    viewer.update();

alert (meshes[1].visible.value);    
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
    function updateview (name,value) {

    var newScene = new JSC3D.Scene;
    var newLoaded = 0;

    var newModelLoaded = function(scene) {
        var newMeshes = scene.getChildren();

        for (var i=1; i<newMeshes.length; i++) {
            newScene.addChild(newMeshes[i]);
            if (newMeshes.length > 0) 
               newMeshes[0].setMaterial(new JSC3D.Material('red-material', 0, colors[newLoaded])); 
        }
        if (++newLoaded == components.length)
            viewer.replaceScene(newScene);
    };

    for (var i=1; i<components.length; i++) {
        var newloader = new JSC3D.StlLoader;
        newloader.onload = newModelLoaded;
        newloader.loadFromUrl(components[i]);
    }
    viewer.update();
};
    </script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add a <div> inside <body> tag say "objectlist".

```
<div id="objectlist"></div>
```

2) After the last viewer.update(); add this little code

```
viewer.onloadingcomplete = function() {
    var shtml ="";

    for(obj in viewer.scene.children) { 
        shtml+="<input type='checkbox' value='" + obj + "' checked onclick='setobject(this);'/>" + viewer.scene.children[object] + "<br />";

    var objects  = document.getElementById(objectlist);
    objects.innerHTML = shtml;
};
```

3) Now add the setobject() function.

```
function setobject(self) { 
    viewer.scene.children[self.value].visible = self.checked; 
}
```

Except point #1 everything should be in javascript code.

That's It...

Enjoy and in case any issues let me know @ *sarillaprasad@yahoo.com* [or] post it here :D